# Clearing CSS Animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Good Day

I have the following CSS Animation:

```
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    color: #000;
    -webkit-animation: moveFromLeftRotate 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveFromLeftRotate 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveFromLeftRotate 300ms ease;
}
```

Now, on a specific page, I would like to add the following jQuery to prevent the animation on that specific page...

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

if(pathname == '/ik/1084-2/'){
     $('.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main').css({
        '-webkit-animation': 'none',
        '-moz-animation': 'none',
        '-ms-animation': 'none'});
}
```

but it does not work - It still shows the animation.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

**Solution:**

CSS:

```
.noAnimation{
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.ca-menu .ca-main').addClass('noAnimation');
```

Thank you everyone for your inputs

Comment: good point. I updated my answer but that is not the problem...was just a typing error here

Comment: try putting `if(true)` in place of `if(pathname == '/ik/1084-2/')`. Path name may have space. `$.trim()` should be used in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you should do is abstract the animation to a separate class, and then use jquery to remove/add the class to elements as necessary

ex.

CSS:

```
.some-animation {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromLeftRotate 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveFromLeftRotate 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveFromLeftRotate 300ms ease;
}
```

Javascript:

```
if (condition) {
    jQuery('#myelement').removeClass('some-animation');
}
```

Comment: I do not want to do it like that. Don't want to change any classes. I am more interested in why it is not working the way I am using it...

Comment: okay, well it does look like you've forgotten to set the `animation` property to `none` - you've only included the vendor specific properties in your code. If that doesn't help, try setting `animation-play-state` to `paused`.

Comment: yeah, I think going the remove/addClass route is best. thank you

Answer (score 3):

CSS animation happens based on some css selectors like class, id etc. Using jQuery, you can remove the css selector to which the animation is defined. I feel you are good removing the animation.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug something like this using below steps

1. Check the FireBug for JS error on the particular page.
2. if(pathname == '/ik/1084-2/'){
        alert('hi'); // check whether your if condition is correct
      }
3. alert(pathname) and see the variable value and see whether it's correct
4. Make sure that this structure $('.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main') exists in the particular page

Comment: no errors, and the pathname part works fine, tested it with an alert()

Comment: thanks, made sure, but it that is not the problem I think. I actually solved the issue by adding a css class clearing the animation...see my updated answer